# Connecting localstack docker container from node js app container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localstack

I am trying to connect localstack docker container from app container. I am using docker-compose file which looks something like below.  `await this.s3Client.send(command)` is failing with `Error: Unable to connect to instance metadata service`

```
   localstack:
    image: ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/localstack:latest
    restart: always  
    ports:
      - '4566:4566'
    expose:
      - '4566'
    networks:
      - service-network
  app:  
    depends_on:    
      - localstack
    build: .
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - |
        npm run build      
        node .
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    volumes:
      - '.:/home/node/app'
    environment:
      - S3_ENDPOINT=http://localstack:4566
    networks:
      - service-network
```

I tried to run same app **outside** the docker container and connected to localstack running(`http://localhost:4566`)in the container. It was successful.

Could you please help how can I connect to localstack container from inside app container.

Comment: Have you tried starting the services separately? If you ran `docker-compose up` it can be so that `localstack` is not ready when `app` tries to reach it. Try `docker-compose up localstack` and once it's ready `docker-compose up app` in another console.

Comment: Tried this. Localstack is running fine. I Started app locally (not inside the container) and tried connecting same localstack with `http://localhost:4566` and it worked fine. But its failing from docker container with `http://localstack:4566`

Comment: Try connecting manually from the `app` container. You can open a shell inside it (if there is one) with `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME sh` and then use `curl` or `wget` to reach `localstack`.

Comment: Yes. I already tried 
```
{"status": "running"}
```

Comment: Only from application its returning ` Unable to connect to instance metadata service` error

Comment: Well then there is no problem with Docker. I suggest you check whether the application make use of the `S3_ENDPOINT` variable.